# Unmatch query not returning expected results

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

apologies in advance as I can't provide sample data. I hope my problem can be answered conceptually.

I want a list of transactions from Table A that are missing corresponding transactions in Table B. Here is my simplified code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*columns*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT
          Customer_ID
          ,Transaction_Date
       FROM TableB)
   b ON a.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
     AND TO_DATE(b.Transaction_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_DATE((a.Transaction_Date - 30), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE((a.Transaction_Date + 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
WHERE (b.Customer_ID||b.Date) IS NULL
```

What I would expect is to return a list of records from Table A where Table B does not contain a record in the preceding 30 days. Instead, I am consistently returning results from Table A that, upon QCing, DO have a Table B match, sometimes on the same day as Table A.

It seems my query is working as an INNER join when what I want is the opposite - a list of things only in Table A.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, `DATE` is invalid column name in Oracle.

All those `TO_DATE` calls look suspicious; what is "`DATE`" column's datatype?

- If `DATE`, it is useless to convert it to `DATE` datatype.
- If `VARCHAR2`, then yes - use `TO_DATE` with appropriate format mask, but what is then `a.date - 30` supposed to return? What is `AFX52 - 30`?

My suggestion is to sort datatypes ambiguity first, then move on. Sample data would certainly help us help you.

Comment: ```DATE``` is not actually called that, edited the post for clarity. I also felt uncomfortable with the ```TO_DATE``` calls. In Table A, ```TRANSACTION_DATE``` is ```DATE``` datatype. In Table B, ```VARCHAR2```. My thought process was that I didn't know if subtracting 30 from the date would leave it in the same format type, so I used the extra ```TO_DATE``` to try to ensure it'd match up with Table B's dates. Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: After you edited it, you are still converting A table's TRANSACTION_DATE - which is already DATE datatype - to "another" date using TO_DATE. Should be `... between a.transaction_date - 30 and a.transaction_date +1`, as simple as that. For the rest, as I said - I prefer seeing sample data. What I imagine is usually not what people really have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if my unmatch was failing due to some weirdness with the unnecessary date conversions OR if it was because concatenating two `NULL` fields produces something other than another `NULL`. Could have been both! Regardless, the following code works as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*columns*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT
          Customer_ID
          ,Transaction_Date
       FROM TableB)
   b ON a.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
     AND TO_DATE(b.Transaction_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN (a.Transaction_Date - 30) AND (a.Transaction_Date + 1)
WHERE (b.Customer_ID IS NULL AND b.Transaction_Date IS NULL)
```

An exercise that was helpful to me while debugging this was to:

1. Comment out the `where` clause
2. Add `b.Customer_ID` and `b.Transaction_Date` to the `select` clause
3. Get a visual that some of the values missing from `TableB` were indeed creating `NULL`s in the join.

Maybe that was just helpful to me because I'm some sort of idiot, but actually seeing the results just made it click that I should try simply using the `AND` rather than a concatenation.